# Changing the static root based on the host in Nginx

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to change the /static/ folder based on the host?

What I want is this:

```
server {

    server_name code-server.domain.com;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding gzip;
    }

    if ($host = code-server.domain.com/proxy/8000) {

    location /static/ {
       root /home/...
    }

    }
```

Is this possible?

I am using code-server, they have a proxy built in. But would I would like to see is when visiting code-server.domain.com/proxy/8000, a different static root loads. (for a development server)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The `$host` holds the value of HTTP request header `Host`. Virtually under no situation, this would contain a URI like in your example config.

Comment: Okay! But is it possible in any other way? A conditional statement that checks the url, and if it matches, it sets a different static root?